# Unknown Host exception from the AWS Java client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Has anyone else run across this exception? We saw it during a load test last night. The hostname is correct and normally works fine. It just started throwing this exception last night. Either it was a random DNS fail on amanzon's part or the Aws SDK for Java does something unexpected under load.

```
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sdb.amazonaws.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:867)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1197)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1064)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:266)
```

Comment: Do you have a leading or trailing space in the hostname string in the code?

Comment: @Jim Nope this url is internal to the AWS Java SDK, Just found out Aws US East was having network connectivity problems last night. So that is the probably cause

Comment: It went away on it own after a while.

Comment: I faced the same issue and it went away on another try.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Change /etc/hosts the following way:
old
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
new
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain add-your-localhost-name-here

Comment: what does this do to help

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: this does not answer

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem 
`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com` while doing [`lein pallet up`](http://palletops.com/) to upload files to aws bucket/ or while trying to get ips of remote machines.

**1. First try,**

Cleaning project, **Waiting for few minutes/hours** and then refiring `lein pallet up -P aws-ec2` with the same aws configuration worked for me.

**2. Second try,**

Run `lein pallet up -P aws-ec2` for single `groups` instead of whole cluster.