# java.net.UnknownHostException for bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the following code to download an s3. This code is from my Android app.

```
public void downloadFile(String baseDir, String imageName) throws IOException {
    this.s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey));

    String s3key = baseDir + "/" + imageName ;

    Log.d(tag, "downloading S3 file with key = " + s3key);

    S3ObjectInputStream content = null;
    try {
        content = s3Client.getObject(bucketName,s3key).getObjectContent();
    } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
        Log.e(tag, "error while downloding S3 file with key = " + s3key ,ex);
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }
```

When I execute this code I get the following exception:

```
02-28 00:48:53.589: D/s3dao(4078): downloading S3 file with key = level1/2_3.jpg
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): Unable to execute HTTP request: fourpicstest.s3.amazonaws.com
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): java.net.UnknownHostException: fourpicstest.s3.amazonaws.com
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:512)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:300)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:259)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:377)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:228)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3215)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1038)
02-28 00:48:54.800: I/AmazonHttpClient(4078): at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:920)
```

However, when I fire the url: fourpicstest.s3.amazonaws.com, I get "access denied exception"

The bucket fourpicstest does exist.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723169/unknown-host-exception-from-the-aws-java-client

Comment: @KEYSER, you could be a good SO editor and fix it yourself, and THEN remind OP that good formatting and grammar are important :)

Comment: @Melquiades Which I did. I don't see how it's something to be called on though. It's not exactly my responsibility.

Comment: @nikis That post is for desktop.my code is for andorid phone

Comment: @KEYSER, 1. Why have you deleted your first comment? 2. You didn't fix code indentations in your edit, which you were calling OP on 3. I'd say that somehow it IS our responsibility as SO users to keep the questions clean, well formatted etc, and educate others on that too. That's just my opinion though, and you, of course, can do as you please.

Comment: SOLVED :  interner permission was missing in manifest file .<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @user93796, post an answer yourself and accept it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT MYSELF: internet permission was missing in manifest file

Adding following to manifest file solved the problem

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```